# Turn numeric values into date format in R

Tags: r, date

I have this ifelse statement in R which deals with date values. Date1 and Date2 are of date format (yyyy-mm-dd), but date_new is generated as a number (like 1630627200). Why this resulting value is so big?
I tried as.Date + origin to turn the number into a date but the result does not have the 4-digit year right (result is like "4466475-08-21"). The incorrect year value is very likely caused by the huge value of date_new.

```
library(lubridate)
df$date_new <- ifelse(is.na(df$date1), df$date2, df$date1)
df$date_new <- as.Date(df$date_new, origin=lubridate::origin)
```

How can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: 1630627200 looks like a POSIXct datetime, in this case June 14 2023, 3:08pm. It counts seconds since Jan 1 1970. Can you edit your question to share an example in code of your data? for instance `dput(head(df))` will make a code recipe for the first 6 rows of data, formats and all.

Comment: I'm guessing that's a time zone conversion issue between POSIXct and getting to Date? I think I've resolved that before by using `lubridate::as_Date()` in place of `as.Date()` and/or by specifying the `tz` in `as.Date`.

Comment: Thank you for the tip!!! I think I found the solution. Will post shortly.

Answer (score 0):

IFELSE statement in R dealing with date fields will generate a new variable of numeric value. Below codes can turn that into the date format (YYYY-mm-dd).

```
library(lubridate)
df$date_new <- ifelse(is.na(df$date1), df$date2, df$date1)
df$date_new <- as.Date(as.character(as.POSIXct(df$date_new, origin=lubridate::origin)))
#This also works: 
as.Date(as.POSIXct(df$date_new,origin ="1970-01-01", tz = "GMT"))
```

Sometimes the resulting date may be one day off because of the time zone issue. The above codes work out well though.